# Can't get $_SERVER to run properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute "opendir" to understand how it works & use it in a recursive page call (I get wrong directories using `..` & `.`).

My folder is constructed as follows:

```
  C:\xampp\htdocs\Ask_Alansky
```

`C:\xampp\htdocs\` is what comes in the XAMPP package, & `Ask_Alansky` is the folder in which I'm working.

The issue is simply that I cannot get a `opendir ()` to work & open the directory. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the concept, but I expect the code to simply open the folder "Ask_Alansky" & show me the files.

My code is:

```
<?php
   opendir($_SERVER['C:/xampp/htdocs/Ask_Alansky'] . '/index.php');
?>
```

I get:

> Notice: Undefined index: C:/xampp/htdocs/Ask_Alansky in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\Ask_Alansky\php_main\Testing.php on line 14
>
> Warning: opendir(/index.php,/index.php): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\Ask_Alansky\php_main\Testing.php on line 14
>
> Warning: opendir(/index.php): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\Ask_Alansky\php_main\Testing.php on line 14

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$_SERVER['C:/xampp/htdocs/Ask_Alansky']` is not valid. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for what `$_SERVER` contains. Just use `'C:/xampp/htdocs/Ask_Alansky'`. Also remove the `/index.php`, since that's a file, not a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER` is an associative array that contains multiple server information. Therefore, there is not such key `C:/xampp/htdocs/Ask_Alansky`. 
If you wish to access the current directory, use [`getcwd()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) instead. It is also not a good idea to use absolute path to your file, this will cause a problem when you migrate your app to another server.